# How to use Camera.AutoFocusCallback with Camera.PreviewCallback in Android?

Tags: android, camera, autofocus

I am developing an Android application which requires me to process visual data. The current outline of the relevant code is as follows:

```
public class ProcessFrames extends Activity implements Camera.PreviewCallback {
   ...
   @override
   public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
       // PROCESSING CODE HERE
   }
   ...
}
```

I want to wait for the camera to complete Autofocus before I start processing the frames. In order to achieve that, I changed the above outline as follows:

```
public class ProcessFrames extends Activity implements Camera.PreviewCallback, Camera.AutoFocusCallback {
   ...

   boolean autoFocusDone = false;

   @Override
   public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
       if(success) autoFocusDone = true;
   }

   @override
   public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
       if(autoFocusDone) {
           // PROCESSING CODE HERE
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

The problem which I am facing is that `boolean autoFocusDone` remains false and as a result, processing code never runs. I do not understand what is it that I am doing wrong. How should I tackle this problem?

I have made sure that the device supports Autofocus and I have set the camera parameters appropriately.